# Is there a way to remove a broken screw?

Tags: screw

I broke the screw that holds the fluid hose going into my power steering pump.  It is a 10 or 12 mm screw head.  What came out is the head plus maybe a quarter inch while the rest is stuck inside.  Is there a way to take the stuck part out, maybe by drilling?  Or will I pretty much have to buy a new pump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, the easiest way to extract the screw is with a screw extractor. Here is a video on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMrDYJvY0Ts) which should explain it pretty good for you. Basically so you know, you drill out the bolt, then put the screw extractor in the hole, then unscrew the broke part. You have to be very careful with your drilling, but this is about the only way you have to get it out besides replacing the entire thing as you've suggested. There are several different types, but the most recognized name brand is the Easy Out.