# Best way to repair/replace broken-off CR-V antenna?

Tags: honda, screw, crv

A 2008 Honda CR-V radio antenna mast has been snapped off (either vandalism or the car wash).  The result is the bottom portion of the machine screw lodged in the cap on the roof of the car where the antenna mounts.

I only noticed that the antenna was actually broken off when I went to screw in a replacement one.  There isn't any thread left to screw a new one into, yet there isn't any of the old screw sticking out enough to remove it from the mount.

What is the best way to extract the remaining piece of the old antenna so I can replace the mast?  Or is it best to try to replace the whole mount assembly (this seems overkill)?

Was Loctite used to secure the OEM antenna?  If not, then maybe [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/9358/5082) method might be best?

Comment: I was going to suggest using a screw extractor as well.

Answer (score 1):

it would be easiest to have it welded back together, but there's a wire that runs from your antennae down through the frame, behind the dashboard..you have to like cut it, and tie the new one on, and fish it through. then i think there's a connector at the end. it's been a while. very difficult if you don't fish it through.

Answer (score 1):

The screw is actually threaded into both parts.  If you cannot grab the remaining stub with a Vice grip or similar, get a set of Easy Outs (A tool specifically made for removing broken screws.  They cost less than ten bucks.) and do it that way.  Once the piece is out of the base the other half is an easy decision... If you can't get the half out of the antenna post, buy a new antenna post.   They can be had for two dollars on a dozen websites.  If you DO get both pieces out, any dealer will have the double ended screw stud in the parts department.  They'll probably give it to you for free.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, attacked it with a tiny drill in a Dremel, intending to create a slot for a screwdriver but the action of the drill just unscrewed it , job done.